# Ubuntu 18.04.1 hang on boot with Nvidia driver installed

Tags: boot, nvidia

I also tried the 396 drivers, but the problem remains. Now I'm forced to use the Nouveau driver. But yet until a week ago, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Nvidia Legacy List here: https://www.nvidia.com/object/IO_32667.html

In the case of Nvidia 390 working, but Nvidia 396 not, Nvidia made the Fermi architecture legacy, I was baffled when my GPU didn't work with the 396 driver, but it turned out to be in the Fermi architecture, so I have to stay on the latest legacy driver (390) now.